# Three cascading Comboboxes

Tags: vba, combobox, userform

I have a relatively large amount of data that I am trying to convert into three `comboboxes` in an `excel userform`. Basically I am trying to create a purchase order system for construction products. This involves the three comboboxes, basically broken down into "Category", "Sub Category" and "Product".

I found some code that uses the `.offset` function, however the only way I found to use this was very time consuming. I am very new to VBA.

Is there a way to use this code or another code to effectively sort through my data rather than me manually changing the offset each time?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim Cell As Range
Dim List As New Collection
Dim Item As Variant
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
LR = Sheet1.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each Cell In .Range("A2:A" & LR)
    With Cell
        On Error Resume Next
        List.Add .Text, CStr(.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
Next Cell
For Each Item In List
    ComboBox1.AddItem Item
    Next Item
End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim Cell As Range
Dim List As New Collection
Dim Item As Variant
Set ws = ActiveSheet


With ws
    LR = Sheet1.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ComboBox2.Clear
    For Each Cell In .Range("A2:A" & LR)
        With Cell
            If .Text = ComboBox1.Value Then
                On Error Resume Next
                List.Add .Offset(0, 1).Text, CStr(.Offset(0, 1).Value)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End With
    Next Cell
    For Each Item In List
        ComboBox2.AddItem Item
    Next Item
End With


End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim Cell As Range
Dim List As New Collection
Dim Item As Variant
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    LR = Sheet1.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ComboBox3.Clear
    For Each Cell In .Range("A2:A" & LR)
        With Cell
            If .Text = ComboBox1.Value Then
                If .Offset(0, 1).Text = ComboBox2.Value Then
                On Error Resume Next
                List.Add .Offset(0, 2).Text, CStr(.Offset(0, 2).Value)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
        End With
    Next Cell
    For Each Item In List
        ComboBox3.AddItem Item
    Next Item
End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Added a fast solution using a datafield array - @RoryAdamson

Answer (score 0):

**Speed it up by using a datafield array**

As far as I understood, your main concern is to achieve improved speed using cascading comboboxes in a UserForm and readable code avoiding numerous `.Offset` .

[i.] Looping through a range is always time consuming, it's **faster** to assign your complete data set to a *variant* **datafield array (`myData`)**.

[ii.] Calling a **single helper procedure** `fillComboNo` makes the `_Change` event procedures *more readable*.

[iii.] The additional helper procedure `SortColl` **sorts** each collection to make selections *user friendly*.

[iv.]  Furthermore this example code allows to **add** *even more comboboxes* using the same helper procedure `fillComboNo` in additional `Combobox{No}_Change` event procedures. - Of course, in this case it would be necessary to extend the range assigned to the datafield array `myData`, too *(i.e. from 3 columns `A:C` to e.g. `A:D`)*.

**Example code**

Basically this solution is close to your approach as it uses collections, too. It is *faster* as it uses a datafield array as described above; *it does not pretend to offer the most efficient way to show cascading comboboxes.*

This example assumes that all needed ComboBoxes are enumerated `ComboBox1`, `ComboBox2`, `ComboBox3`, ...

```
Option Explicit                                     ' declaration head of the UserForm code module
Dim myData                                          ' Variant 2-dim datafield array ( 1-based !)

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim LR   As Long, ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Sheet1                                   ' if using CodeName in thisWorkbook
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' [0] get entire DATA FIELD                         ' e.g. columns A:C (omitting title row)
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row     ' get last row
  myData = ws.Range("A2:C" & LR).Value2             ' <<  assign range values to datafield array

' [1] fill first ComboBox
  FillComboNo 1                                     ' <~~ helper procedure FillComboNo
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    FillComboNo 2                                   ' <~~ helper procedure FillComboNo
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    FillComboNo 3                                   ' <~~ helper procedure FillComboNo
End Sub
```

**Helper procedure `FillComboNo`**

```
Sub FillComboNo(ByVal no As Long)
' Purpose: fill cascading comboboxes
' Note:    assumes controls named as "ComboBox" & No (ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ...)
Dim myList As New Collection
Dim item   As Variant
Dim i      As Long, ii As Long
Dim OK     As Boolean, OKTemp As Boolean
' [0] clear ComboBox{No}
  Me.Controls("ComboBox" & no).Clear
' [1] assign values in column No based on prior hierarchy levels
  For i = LBound(myData) To UBound(myData)
    ' [1a] check upper hierarchy
      OK = True
      For ii = 1 To no - 1
          OKTemp = myData(i, ii) = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & ii): OK = OK And OKTemp
      Next ii
    ' [1b] add to collection
      If OK Then
         On Error Resume Next
         myList.Add myData(i, no), myData(i, no)
         If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear
      End If
  Next i
' [1c] sort collection via helper procedure
      SortColl myList                               ' <~~ helper procedure SortColl
' [2] fill ComboBox{No}
  For Each item In myList
      Me.Controls("ComboBox" & no).AddItem item
  Next item
End Sub
```

**Sorting routine `SortColl`**

```
Sub SortColl(ByRef c As Collection)
' Purpose: sort collection by keys via bubble sort method
  Dim i     As Long, j As Long
  Dim vTemp As Variant
  For i = 1 To c.Count - 1
      For j = i + 1 To c.Count
          If c(i) > c(j) Then
            ' remember the lesser item
              vTemp = c(j)
            ' remove the lesser item
              c.Remove j
            ' add the lesser item before the greater one
              c.Add vTemp, vTemp, i
          End If
      Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```